# How many ways to divide a population of n members into groups of i members.

Tags: combinatorics

Let's say I have a population of 180, to be divided in disjoint groups of 6. In how many different ways can I divide this population? A general formula would help! Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are $180!$ ways to line the people up, and we can then group them from positions $1-6$, $7-12$, and so on.

However, we are double counting in two ways.  First, within each group of $6$ we are double counting by a factor of $6!$.  Then, we can arrange the groups in $30!$ different ways.  We thus have the following answer:

$$\frac{180!}{(6!)^{30}30!}$$

This is a large number by the way, on the order of $10^{211}$.  In general, with $n$ people and $k$ people per group, where $n=km$, the formula is:

$$\frac{n!}{(k!)^mm!}$$